# Fill in the blank to make true identities: $(A\Delta B)\cap C=(C\setminus A)\Delta(\_\_\_)$, $A,B,C$ set of real numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

I'm come across a problem regarding set theory and operations, it goes like this:

Fill in the blank to make true identities
$$(A\Delta B)\cap C=(C\setminus A)\Delta(\_\_\_)$$

Where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are set of real numbers.

The problem that I encounter is when I fill out $(A\Delta B)\cap C$, I got this as the following:

[Figure 1. $(A\Delta B)\cap C$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJVf2.png)

and when I fill out $(C\setminus A)$ the graph is going to look like this:
[graph of (C\A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra2Eo.png)

but $(\Delta)$ denoted as the symmetric difference between the two set, or the shaded region will be in the sets but not at their intersection. However, given the condition in which I have to make the identity true, $(\Delta)$ is not sufficient to cancel out the elements of C to make the right side of the equation look like the left side of the equation. Could anyone give me a hint on what to do? Thank you

Comment: You can write $A\Delta B$ as $(A \cup B)\backslash (A \cap B)$. Then you can try to use boolean algebra so simplify the things. This is what I would do, without having the solution in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you already found out in your diagram, what the left site of your equation is.

Now on the right site of your equation, you have $(C \backslash A)\Delta X$. $X$ is then the union of what you want to "add" to $(C \backslash A)\Delta X$ and of what you want to remove from $(C \backslash A)\Delta X$, so that it gives you the left site. This is just because of the definition of $\Delta$. Make it clear to you with an easy example.

By using your diagram, you can see then that $X = C \backslash B$.

Comment: Did you mean $C \setminus B$?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Im sorry. Thank you.

Comment: thank you! Now I see how it works, my mind keep thinking that symmetric difference take the elements out at the intersection at the rings, and forgot that in symmetric difference, the elements of two sets are taken out when they overlapped. So I keep thinking that there's no way to cancel out the left over elements in set C. Now I know, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If this helped you, don't forget to flag it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:
$$
blank = C- B
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint

If $(A\Delta B)\cap C = (C\setminus A)\Delta(\underline\quad)$

Then by symmetry: $(B\Delta A)\cap C = (C\setminus B)\Delta(\underline\quad)$

(Just verify that there is no third term and your should be done.)